# How to get a CiviRule to fill in a custom field upon a webform submission?

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm, civirules, drupal-7

We have a Drupal 7 website that we are having users submit a webform on. When a webform is submitted it is assigned a unique ID. This ID used to generate a PDF to view the webform results and is viewable on the Drupal side. The problem we are running into is getting this information over to the CiviCRM side automatically. We created a custom data field in CiviCRM for the ID to go in and have it left blank during the submission, and we installed the module CiviRules Webform CiviCRM Submission Trigger so we can have a rule run when the form is submitted. The part we need help with is getting a rule that takes that ID and fills in the blank field with it upon submission or some way to do the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to develop an action that can take that ID from the data coming into the action and set it. There is a standard action to update a custom field (Set Custom Field) but it will ask for a value and will not be able to pick up the value from the input just like that.

Developing your own action is documented here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/

An alternative might be to use the Form Processor extension, and pick up the ID from the incoming data like that. Check the documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/formprocessor/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional_values with Webform-CiviCRM integration if the ID is known before submission.  If it's not available until after submission, you'll need to write code.  Erik suggests one way, you could also write a Drupal module to push it to Civi.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not developers, you can hire one from https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors, including ErikH or Jon G (or us ;) ).